# Postgres conditional aggregate array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a self referencing, tree structure containing features of an application. Through other two many-to-many tables I would like to know which features a user can access.

```
app_user (id, name, is_superuser)
feature (id, parent_id, name)
job (id, name)
job_feature_relationship (job_id, feature_id, deny)
job_user_relationship (job_id, user_id)
```

Summarizing: Users can have multiple jobs. A job contains a set of features, with the option to deny. This is useful for managing permissions in a tree structure, e.g.:

there are the following features:

```
sales

sales/product
sales/product/createProduct
sales/product/deleteProduct
sales/product/listProducts

sales/customer
sales/customer/createCustomer
sales/customer/deleteCustomer
sales/customer/listCustomers
```

Only the leaf nodes (`createProduct`, `deleteProduct`, `listProducts`, `createCustomer`, `deleteCustomer`, `listCustomers`) are actual actions.

If the job looks like this:

`(sales)`

The user should be able to do all actions under sales, so in this example all actions.

However if the job would look like this:

`(sales/customer)`

`(sales/customer/deleteCustomer, deny)`

The user should only be able to `listCustomers` and `createCustomer`, as of `sales/customer` would allow everything in the subtree, but `deleteCustomer` gets a denial.

A final addition, not exactly relevant for this problem, but `superuser` users can access all features, meaning if the if_superuser bool flag is set to true, all features should be accessible regardless of jobs.

I am one step away from the solution.

```sql
with recursive
feature_tree(parent, child, name, level) as (
    select id, id, feature, 1
    from feature
    union all
    select parent, id, feature.feature, feature_tree.level + 1
    from feature_tree
    join feature on (
        feature_tree.child = feature.parent_id
    )
)
select
    feature_tree.name
    , feature_tree.level
    , deny
from feature
join feature_tree on (
    feature_tree.parent = feature.id
)
left join job_feature_relationship on (
    job_feature_relationship.feature_id = feature.id
)
left join job_user_relationship on (
    job_user_relationship.job_id = job_feature_relationship.job_id
)
join app_user on (
    -- app_user.id = 1
    app_user.id = 2
    -- app_user.id = 3
    -- app_user.id = 4
)
where (
    -- this condition is responsible for only returning leafs
    not exists(select 1 from feature descendant where descendant.parent_id = feature_tree.child)
    and (
        app_user.is_superuser
        or job_user_relationship.user_id = app_user.id
    )
)
order by feature_tree.level desc;
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0a206/5)

What I would like can be very easily described sequentially, python example code:

```py
features = set()
for feature in features:
    if feature.deny:
        features = features.difference(feature.tree)
    else:
        features = features.union(feature.tree)
```

Because of the ordering, adding and removing set of features will have the correct final result.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please give us a set of sample data we can work with. This is highly complex and very hard to generate own data for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I updated my question with more reasonable example data and an sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, 5 minutes after creating all the fiddles and descriptions I have succeeded with the problem. The solution was a different approach, instead of aggregating in fancy ways, what i had to do was check the denial flag on the lowest possible level.

```sql
with recursive
feature_tree(parent, child, name, level) as (
    select id, id, feature, 1
    from feature
    union all
    select parent, id, feature.feature, feature_tree.level + 1
    from feature_tree
    join feature on (
        feature_tree.child = feature.parent_id
    )
)
, all_features(name, deny) as (
    select distinct on (feature_tree.name)
        feature_tree.name
        , not app_user.is_superuser and deny
    from feature
    join feature_tree on (
        feature_tree.parent = feature.id
    )
    left join job_feature_relationship on (
        job_feature_relationship.feature_id = feature.id
    )
    left join job_user_relationship on (
        job_user_relationship.job_id = job_feature_relationship.job_id
    )
    join app_user on (
        app_user.id = 4
    )
    where (
        (
            app_user.is_superuser
            or job_user_relationship.user_id = app_user.id
        )
        and not exists(
          select 1 
          from feature descendant 
          where descendant.parent_id = feature_tree.child
        )
    )
    order by feature_tree.name, feature_tree.level
)
select name
from all_features
where not deny;
```

The key figure is the `distinct on (name)` and `order by name, level`.
However i'm not sure about the performance, I had to create another cte, because the distinct on did not let me filter them properly.